# Implementing an efficient container for storing edges in a graph

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, graph, dijkstra

I need to efficiently define an ordering on the `std::set<Edge>`. Edge represents an edge in a graph (not multigraph).

```
class Edge
    {
        friend class Graph;
        string from;
        string to;
        EdgeInfo edge_length; //constructor is `EdgeInfo(int edge_length)`
    public:
        bool operator==(const Edge& rhs) {
            return (from==rhs.from && to==rhs.to);               
        }
    };
```

The problem is to efficiently find

- whether the `std::set<Edge>` contains an edge with given "from" and "to"
- edges that go from given "from" to some "to", where "to" is not inside a given `set<string>`

using `std::set.count()` and `std::set.find()`. I need to somehow define the appropriate ordering on the `std::set`. Is this possible?

---

**EDIT**: I figured I should have used `map` or `multimap` instead of `set`. Eventually I used `map`. The solution is inspired by @tom's suggestion to use `map of maps`.

---

**SOLUTION**:

```
typedef int EdgeInfo; //just for the sake of this example (EdgeInfo can be length,price,...) 
map< string, map<string, EdgeInfo> > edges;
```

> whether the `std::set<Edge>` contains an edge with given "from" and
>   "to"

```
if (edges.count(from)!=0 && edges[from].count(to)!=0) {
        return true; 
}
```

or in case the function is `const`

```
if (edges.count(from)!=0 && ((edges.find(top.second))->second).count(to)!=0) {
        return true; 
}
```

> edges that go from given "from" to some "to", where "to" is not inside
>   a given set

in case the function is `const`

```
//if there are any edges from "from"
if (edges.count(from)!=0) {  

    //iterate over all edges from "from"
    for (map<string,EdgeInfo>::const_iterator
                 edge=((edges.find(from))->second).begin();
                 edge!=((edges.find(from))->second).end();
                 ++edge) {

        //if the edge goes to some vertex V that has not been discarded
        if (discarded.count(edge->first)==0) { //edge->first means "to"
```

Comment: Your `if` statement is dangerous. It should be, `if (condition == true && true) { return true && condition == true ? true : false } else { return condition == false ? !true : false; }`.

Comment: Am I the only one who doesn't even remotely understand your comment, @KerrekSB?

Comment: @Cornstalks I think Kerrek is humorously pointing out that `if (cond) return true; else return false` can be written as `return cond`.

Comment: @tom: I was hoping so...

Comment: @KerrekSB You were right, I corrected it.
@tom I can't. I would need something like an associative array (which is not in C++) because `x` and `y` are `string`. Even if I used them, I would have problem adding one more vertex to the graph as the array size is fixed. Moreover, I would need to use pointer to indicate by `NULL` there is no edge between vertices which brings memory issues...

Comment: @user1459339 Sorry, I didn't notice the node IDs were strings. I removed my comment and added an answer which takes that into account.

Comment: @KerrekSB : It took me a minute (and looking at the edit history), but +1 for a good laugh sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Adjacency List

```
map< string, set<string> > edges;
// edges["a"] is the set of all nodes that can be reached from "a"

// O(log n)
bool exists(string from, string to)
{
    return edges[from].count(to) > 0;
}

// Ends of edges that start at 'from' and do not finish in 'exclude', O(n)
set<string> edgesExcept(string from, set<string>& exclude)
{
    set<string>& fromSet = edges[from];
    set<string> results;
    // set_difference from <algorithm>, inserter from <iterator>
    set_difference(fromSet.begin(), fromSet.end(),
            exclude.begin(), exclude.end(),
            inserter(results, results.end()));
    return results;
}
```

#### Adjacency Matrix

```
map< string, map<string, Edge*> > edgesMatrix;
// edgesMatrix["a"]["b"] is the Edge* from "a" to "b"
// e.g. Edge* e = new Edge(...); edgesMatrix[e->from][e->to] = e;

bool exists(string from, string to)
{
    return edgesMatrix[from].count(to) > 0;
}

vector<Edge*> edgesExcept(string from, set<string>& exclude)
{
    map<string, Edge*>& all = edgesMatrix[from];
    vector<Edge*> results;

    map<string, Edge*>::iterator allIt = all.begin();
    set<string>::iterator excludeIt = exclude.begin();

    while (allIt != all.end())
    {
        while (excludeIt != exclude.end() && *excludeIt < allIt->first)
        {
            ++excludeIt;
        }

        if (excludeIt == exclude.end() || allIt->first < *excludeIt)
        {
            results.push_back(allIt->second);
        }
        ++allIt;
    }

    return results;
}
```

#### One Ordered Set

This is more in line with the OP's original request, but I feel it is much uglier than the other options.
I have included this only for the sake of completeness.

```
// sorted first by 'from', then by 'to'
class Edge {
    // ...
public:
    bool operator<(const Edge& r) const {
        return from < r.from || (from == r.from && to < r.to);
    }
};

set<Edge> edges;

bool exists(string from, string to) {
    Edge temp(from, to, -1);
    return edges.count(temp) > 0;
}

set<Edge> edgesExcept(string from, set<string>& exclude) {
    Edge first = Edge(from, "", -1); // ugly hack: "" sorts before other to's
    set<Edge> results;

    set<Edge>::iterator allIt = edges.lower_bound(first);
    set<string>::iterator excludeIt = exclude.begin();

    while (allIt != edges.end() && allIt->from == from) {
        while (excludeIt != exclude.end() && *excludeIt < allIt->to) {
            ++excludeIt;
        }
        if (excludeIt == exclude.end() || allIt->to < *excludeIt) {
            results.insert(results.end(), *allIt);
        }
        ++allIt;
    }
    return results;
}
```

#### Explanation of `edgesExcept()`

Here is a pseudo code version:

```
for each edge e in edges_of_interest (in sorted order)
    get rid of edges in exclude_edges that sort before e
    if e is equal to the first edge in exclude_edges
        e is in exclude_edges, so
        ignore e (i.e. do nothing)
    otherwise
        e is not in exclude_edges, so
        add e to good_edges
```

Instead of actually removing edges that are no longer relevant from `exclude_edges`, the C++ version uses an iterator to remember which edges in `exclude_edges` are no longer relevant (those smaller than all the edges of interest that are yet to be examined). Once all the edges in `exclude_edges` that are smaller than `e` have been removed / skipped over, checking if `e` appears in `exclude_edges` can be done simply by comparing it to the first (smallest) element of `exclude_edges`.

Comment: I actually like your last solution the best! If you search for the endpoint with `upper_bound()`, you could just use `set_difference()` with a custom comparator function that compares the `to` field of an `Edge` with a `string` to build the result set.  (Not sure if this would save much space though.)

Answer (score 0):

For what reason you should use a multimap for this kind of work? I think Map is enough, if I understand well, you don't need to keep the same node on your graph.

If you decide to use a Map, it's easy to find an existing edge and also your second question. You need only to search the key and iterate your map. 
With Set, elements are inserted in random order, so, this mean a long time for your search (O (N).
If you store your elements in a map (I think the best way is to use "from" as key), the insert will be ordered, your search use a time of O(Log n)

If you need to modify the connections in your graph,  the set elements cannot be modified if they are in the set, in a map you can.

Comment: But what if there is an edge from A to B and another edge from A to C? I can map A to only one other vertex.

Comment: You can use edge A as key and a vector of edge as key, or, if your edge is identified by a name a concatenation of string as key, or the multimap. Multimap has the same efficiency as Map.

Comment: Sorry, I want to say "A as key and a vector of edges as value" :)

Comment: You said "With Set, elements are inserted in random order", but I believe that `std::set` is implicitly ordered. I think @tom is coming with an elegant solution.